# pass the foreign key of a model in the url

Tags: django

I've two different models with the names TvShow and Episode but episode is connected with tvshow through a foreign key

```
tvshow = models.ForeignKey(Media, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

so I was trying to add it to urls of episode model like this

```
path('<str:tvshow_title>/<int:season_number>/<int:episode_number>', views.episode, name='episode')
```

but the views.py of Episode have a hard time defining it:

```
def episode(request, tvshow_title, season_number, episode_number):

    tvshow = Media.objects.filter(media_type='TV', title=tvshow_title).first()

    episode = get_object_or_404(
        Episode, tvshow=tvshow, season_number=season_number, episode_number=episode_number)

    context = {
        'episode': episode
    }

    return render(request, 'media/episode.html', context)
```

I'm not sure what the problem is I'm not sure if this is how you pass more than one parameter to get_object_or_404.

Comment: what error is being thrown here? You seem to have get_object_or_404 correct, but get_or_404 will throw an error if no match is found, but also if more than one match is found, and you aren't handling either.

Comment: You should show the code about fields of TvShow and Episode models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), you can use the filter directly in `get_object_or_404`

```
episode = get_object_or_404(
    Episode, tvshow__title=tvshow_title, tvshow__media_type='TV', season_number=season_number, episode_number=episode_number)
```